# What's the _type column for a polymorphic used for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, polymorphism

From the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), to establish a polymorphic relationship on one model, I need to add two columns for the corresponding table.

As the image below shows, the `_id` column is used as a foreign key. But I cannot figure out the usage of the `_type` column? What's the usage of it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `_type` column is used to identify what resource this comes from. In this case, the polymorphic resource could be one of `Employee` or a `Product`. In other words: an image can relate to *either* a product or an employee.

The `_type` column will simply contain the string of either "Employee" or "Product". When this association is accessed, Rails will use it to know what model to use to load the associated object.

Comment: Or equivalently, `_type` tells you which model/table to look at and `_id` tells you which instance/row.

Comment: Excellent description, Mr. mu.

Comment: My dad's Mr. mu, I'm just mu :)

Comment: @muistooshort Does it mean an polymorphic object/instance/record could only be related to **either one** of them but never **both of them**?

Comment: @steven.yang: Yes it does. The Employee can point straight at the Picture with a single ID but the Picture needs two things (type and ID) to point back.